# Only positive or only negative variable in a clause of the form $x_1 \lor x_2 \lor \lnot x_3,$

Tags: logic

Say, you have an expression like

$$x_1 \lor x_2 \lor  \lnot x_3,$$

and you want to rewrite this as an equivalent expression where all variables are either negative or positive and the expression still has the form of a clause, how would you accomplish this?

I think it's easy to rewrite a negative variable as a positive variable. It should work like this:

$$\lnot x_3 := (x_3 \lor y_3) \land (\lnot x_3 \lor \lnot y_3)$$

with $y_3 = true$ iff $x_3 = false$. In this case, $(x_3 \lor y_3) \land (\lnot x_3 \lor \lnot y_3) = true$ iff $x_3 = false$, which is thus equivalent to $\lnot x_3$.

So we can rewrite te expression from above as

$$x_1 \lor x_2 \lor  ((x_3 \lor y_3) \land (\lnot x_3 \lor \lnot y_3)),$$

so now it is a clause that consists of only positive variables.

But how would I do it if I want to rewrite a positive variable  as a negative variable?

Comment: Try De Morgan's law on $x_1 \vee x_2$

Comment: Applying De Morgan's law wouldn't be allowed since the expression wouldn't be a clause anymore then.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)